# Python equivalent of omitting second part of ternary operator (a if a else b)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-operator

In some languages (I think php and Java) you can omit the second part of the ternary operator as such:

```
a = "This is a string"
result = a ? : False
```

The above should be equivalent to

```
a = "This is a string"
result = a ? a : False
```

I want to shorten the ternary operator in the following (simplified) python code:

```
def myFunc():
   return "This string could be empty, but now it's not."

result = myFunc() if myFunc() else False
print(result)
```

This will print the string if it's not empty, but print False when it is empty.

The reason why I want it shorter is because now, I have to call myFunc() two times instead of just once if you were able to omit one of them as is possible in other languages.

Of course I could just assign myFunc() to a variable and use the variable twice in the ternary operator but this would make it bigger again.

Is there any easy way to do this in python? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: "Of course I could just assign myFunc() to a variable and use the variable twice in the ternary operator but this would make it bigger again." So what? Just assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `or` here as an empty string evaluates as a Falsey value:

```
result = myFunc() or False
```

Refer to [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: I tested it, and that's exactly what I wanted! I don't understand why this works though? Shouldn't result be True instead of returning the value of the string since a non-empty string would evaluate to True which would make the statement: `result = True or False` which would be True?

Comment: This is a conditional statement. It checks the truth value of the left argument and if it is true it returns it's value otherwise it returns the value on the right. See [PEP-0308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for more reading on this.